# Is there an open source immutable dictionary for C#, with fast 'With/Without' methods?

Tags: c#, dictionary, immutability

I'm looking for a proper C# immutable dictionary, with fast update methods (that create a partial copy of the dictionary with slight changes). I've implemented one myself, using zippers to update a red-black tree, but it's not particularly fast.

By 'immutable dictionary' I don't just mean readonly or const. I want something that has reasonably fast 'With' and 'Without', or equivalent, methods that return a thing with slight modifications without modifying the original.

An example from another language is [map in Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some [implementation of the immutable dictionary](https://github.com/ptony82/brunet/blob/master/src/Brunet/Collections/ImmutableDictionary.cs) based on read-only binary AVL tree.

```
/**
 * To modify, use the InsertIntoNew and RemoveFromNew methods
 * which return a new instance with minimal changes (about Log C),
 * so this is an efficient way to make changes without having
 * to copy the entire data structure.
 */
```

Please take a look at the `InsertIntoNew()` method:

```
/** Return a new tree with the key-value pair inserted
 * If the key is already present, it replaces the value
 * This operation is O(Log N) where N is the number of keys
 */
public ImmutableDictionary<K,V> InsertIntoNew(K key, V val)
{ ... }
```

The `RemoveFromNew()` method:

```
/** Try to remove the key, and return the resulting Dict
 * if the key is not found, old_node is Empty, else old_node is the Dict
 * with matching Key
 */
public ImmutableDictionary<K,V> RemoveFromNew(K key, out ImmutableDictionary<K,V> old_node)
{ ... }
```

Also, there is another implementation: [Immutable AVL Tree in C#](http://justinmchase.com/2011/12/13/immutable-avl-tree-in-c/). It has the same O(log N) lookup and insertion times.

## Additional references

- Seems to be a mirror: [brunet/ImmutableDictionary.cs at master · johnynek/brunet · GitHub](https://github.com/johnynek/brunet/blob/master/src/Brunet/Collections/ImmutableDictionary.cs).
- Seems to be similar: [ImmutableCollections/ImmutableDictionary.cs at master · mono/ImmutableCollections · GitHub](https://github.com/mono/ImmutableCollections/blob/master/System.Collections.Immutable/System.Collections.Immutable/ImmutableDictionary.cs).

Comment: first link is dead

Comment: @kofifus, thanks! Have added «Additional references».